# Android EditText how to start cursor pointer at the end of all characters- not end of first line

Tags: android

I have comment  box using EditText and it has several lines.  When user returns to the box they are always at end of line 1 rather than end of say line 3 if there are three lines total in the box.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14):

There might be easier ways perhaps, but one way is to use

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

You can place this line inside an [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html), or in a Create method.

Comment: To place the cursor at the end of the text, it should be just `editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());`

Comment: This did not work for me.  I have Spannable strings in my EditText.  Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this 
 final int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
 final int selectionend = editText.getText().length();

Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), selectionStart, selectionend);

Please make you are not calling setText after this because that will override the behavior.